# Can ng-include load controller defined within including html file in <script> tags (or any other way)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**main.html**

```
<script src="main.js">
     var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
</script>
<div ng-include="'login.html'"></div>
```

**login.html**

```
    <script src="Components/LoginModule/LoginCtrl.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
        <form-field ng-field-data="{{login.usr_name}}"></form-field>
        <form-field ng-field-data="{{login.password}}"></form-field>
    </div>
```

i defined LoginCtrl controller in **LoginCtrl.js**, and want it to be loaded alongwith ng-include.

But i am facing following error

> [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'LoginCtrl' is not
>   registered.

where as if i define my controller in **main.html**, it work perfectly fine

Comment: This is lazy loading. It's not officially supported by the framework. Use third-party solutions like ozLazyLoad.

Comment: i kind of solved it by using $(selector).load(url) instead of using nginclude. and bootstraping the loaded div manually